# Compare each pair of samples in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe of samples with categorical and numerical attributes. I would like to compare each pair of samples in a way that you take one and compare it against all the other samples. This comparison is performed by means of a function that has two parameters (the two samples in comparison).

Let us suppose that *data2* is that dataframe and *ComputeSimilarityMeasure* is the function that I would like to apply. It is worth saying that this function separates categorical and numerical attributes in order to perform different calculations with them.

I have tried this:

```
nsamples=nrow(data2)
for (i in 1:nsamples) {
  KX(i) <- apply( data2, 1, function(x) ComputeSimilarityMeasure(x,data2[i,]) )
  #...rest of the code...
}
```

The problem is that, inside the *ComputeSimilarityMeasure* the sample *x* has all its attributes as strings, even numerical ones. Therefore, the function doesn't work properly.

Input sample to the function (before the call):

```
KEY_PROMO PROMO_TYPE KEY_STORE KEY_MKT   MKT_HQ_CITY   MKT_HQ_STATE
1         0          1         6         Chicago       IL
```

Input sample to the function (inside the function):

```
KEY_PROMO PROMO_TYPE KEY_STORE KEY_MKT   MKT_HQ_CITY   MKT_HQ_STATE
   "   1"      "  0"     " 1"     " 6"   "Chicago             " "IL
```

At this moment, I have implemented two *for* loops for solving the problem (working fine), however, this solution is unacceptable in terms of computation time (*data2* has thousands of samples).

Any idea about fixing my *apply* function? Any other alternative that you estimate better?

Comment: Apply turns your dataframe to a matrix, which can only contain one data type.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know that .... so any alternative to do this job??

Comment: If your "ComputeSimilarityMeasure" takes 2 ''scalar'' samples to compare, you can't avoid 2 loops (either as `for`, `apply`, `mapply`, etc) to compare all to all. Perhaps, your function can/can be made to accept a sample as the first argument and sampleS (i.e. all rows) as its second argument and return the comparison of 1 to all? That way, you could loop only once. If your function compares 1 to 1, then, I guess, your two `for ` loops cannot be avoided and you focus to efficiency fixes to the `for`s like avoid subsetting same things again and again, avoid re-allocating again and again etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sapply like for loop

```
nsamples=nrow(data2)
for (i in 1:nsamples) {
  KX(i) <- sapply(1:nrow(data2), function(x) ComputeSimilarityMeasure(data2[x,],data2[i,]) )
  #...rest of the code...
}
```

If your data set is big enough to parallelize this procedure. I recommend `mclapply` instead of `for`